# Enter key press not firing event on mx:list item in flex

Tags: flex4, keyboard-events

i am doing a web application in flex. i have a list of items in mx:List control.
 Mouse click on each item triggering an itemClick event and goes fine.
 But when i press Enter key on focused items in the list, it is not triggering the event.
 How can i enable my enter key to fire the event.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a keyDown event listener to the list then add a function to check if the enter key is hit:

```
private function checkKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        Alert.show(myList.selectedItem + " selected");
    }
}
```

And:

```
<mx:List id="myList" keyDown="checkKeyDown(event)">
```